# Error received when pinning a message in Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When anyone pins a message in discord the following error causes the bot to crash (with forever it recovers but still not the point). The message that is pinned can be any type (regular or embed).

```
    if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
                      ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
    at ..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (..........................................\index.js:323:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (..........................................\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
```

Does anyone know why??

Code requested starting at line 318 to 336

```js
const logs = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
    const notifyAdminEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff6600')
        .setTitle('Keyword Used in Message')
        .setDescription('@here, A member mentioned a keyword you wished to be notified about. Please investigate immediately.')
        .addFields({
            name: 'Message Author',
            value: `<@` + message.author.id + `>`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Channel',
            value: `<#` + message.channel.id + `>`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Message',
            value: message.content,
            inline: false
        })
        .setTimestamp()
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? specifically around line 320 in index.js

Comment: @mmoomocow edited original post

Comment: Have you tried logging each value - i.e. `console.log("<@" + message.author.id + ">")` - just because normal syntax for this would be ``<@${message.author.id}>``

Comment: I changed the syntax with the same exact result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what caused the issue just not sure why. I changed the code to look like below and it no longer throws that error. Only difference is the message.content now has a space before and after.

```js
const logs = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
    const notifyAdminEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff6600')
        .setTitle('Keyword Used in Message')
        .setDescription('@here, A member mentioned a keyword you wished to be notified about. Please investigate immediately.')
        .addFields({
            name: 'Message Author',
            value: `<@` + message.author.id + `>`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Channel',
            value: `<#` + message.channel.id + `>`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Message',
            value: ' ' + message.content + ' '
            inline: false
        })
        .setTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a feeling `message.content` is undefined (or not there, empty string etc) , maybe try logging it?,
i would have commented but i am not at rep 50

^^ this is a guess as all the other values seems to be okay

Comment: Message.content is defined. This embed does exactly as it should.

Comment: well, i just guessed that was the issue because all the other values are filled, with these (<@) or other parts and message content was just there, so if the message did not have any content, message will be undefined